# Does using ios-aws-sdk pass everything over SSL

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I use AWS Lambda as a backend service to authenticate users from my ios app.  When learning about Lambda I was pointed to use the Amazon API Gateway to make the data over the network go over HTTPS:// and NOT HTTP://.

Someone recently pointed out that all calls to AWS Lambda, DynamoDB, S3, and Cognito directly from my app automatically go over HTTPS://. Is this true or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the docs are not explicit on the matter, that I could find, but inspecting the source on github:

[AWSService](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/a90e23e88e13444c89e2bb1668ff74c15d47b75c/AWSCore/Service/AWSService.m#L406), one of the base services used by the sdk, uses https by default, and will only switch to http if the AWSServiceConfiguration particular configuration is established with the parameter `useUnsafeUrl` set to true.

And [AWSLambdaService](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/a90e23e88e13444c89e2bb1668ff74c15d47b75c/AWSLambda/AWSLambdaService.m#L268), even if initialised with a configuration object, appears to set the `useUnsafeUrl` option to `NO`.

So - inspection of the source suggests that all access to the service is by default https.

This is consistent with AWS SDK defaults in other languages/frameworks as well.

#### -- Edited to note --

I had a thought after posting this - it's possible that the advice to use API Gateway for https was based on the common practice of exposing Lambda functions as API endpoints.  If you want to do that, then API Gateway gives you a way, and if you are using API Gateway, then you *do* need to ensure it is configured to use https.

What is not clear from your question is - from your app, are you invoking the lambda functions via the API Gateway endpoint? Or directly via the AWS SDK?  If invoking directly via the AWS SDK then there is no need to use API Gateway at all.

If you are already using the API Gateway, and issuing HTTPS web requests to invoke your lambda functions, I wouldn't necessarily stop, because it gives you a nice point of abstraction and decoupling - you could completely change your backend implementation and as long as you keep the API Gateway endpoint configuration the same, your clients will still work.  Alternatively, you could start to implement other clients or expose your API to 3rd party clients who aren't in a position to use AWS SDK and they will still be able to interract with your backend via standard HTTP protocols.

Comment: Your 3rd paragraph after the Edited to note is the correct one. I decided to use the api gateway to access lambda functions to create an abstract and https authentication system. I will keep doing it that way. I was unaware that passing a password to lambda directly through the aws ios sdk would use https so i did the gateway anyway.

Comment: Documentation is not explicit, but after viewing source code it's pretty clear that _if_ you use an HTTPS–enabled endpoint, calls made directly via the SDK will be HTTPS. Furthermore, all Lambda endpoints are HTTPS: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#lambda_region.